# Level unlocking corona sdk

Tags: lua, coronasdk, simulator, game-development

I'm having an issue with my loading of level information when I complete a level.  When one level is complete a button becomes visible and when clicked it changes the table to make the next level unlocked. It worked for the first level and showed the first level complete unlocked, but no other levels. My code is below, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
function levelMod(event)
    if (levels[1]) then
       levels[1] = 3
       levels[2] = 1
       composer.gotoScene(event.target.destination,{effect="fade"})
       return true
    else
       composer.gotoScene(event.target.destination,{effect="fade"})
       return true
    end
end

nextBtn = display.newText("Next level",0,0,"Helvetica",15)
nextBtn.x=display.screenOriginX+200
nextBtn.y=display.contentHeight-5
nextBtn.destination = "gotoPlay"
nextBtn:addEventListener("touch",levelMod)
nextBtn.isVisible = false
sceneGroup:insert(nextBtn)

function gameOver(condition)
    if(condition =="WINNER") then
        screenText.text="Amazing!";
        nextBtn.isVisible= true
    elseif(condition =="Not Bad") then
        screenText.text="Not To Shabby."
        nextBtn.isVisible = true
    elseif (conditon =="loser") then
        screenText.text="You Can Do Better.";
    end
end
```

The `gameOver` function is called from a different function and if winner or not bad then the button becomes visible, then when clicked the button goes to my play file which holds my table with levels. It uses the `levelMod` function to unlock the levels.

```
local levelsave = require("levelSave")

levels = {
  1,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,
  2,2,2,2,2,
}

levels = loadInfo() 

images ={
  { getFile="unlock.png", types="play" },
  { getFile="lock .png", types="locked" },
  { getFile="greenchecked.png", types="done" }
}
```

That's in the main chunk of my play file which sets the table to locked or unlocked. Then:

```
saveInfo()
```

is put in my show event scene.

```
local json = require("json")

function loadInfo()
    local base = system.pathForFile("levels.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local jsoncontents = ""
    local levelsArray = {}
    local file = io.open(base,"r")
    if file then
        local jsoncontents = file:read("*a")
        levelsArray = json.decode(jsoncontents);
        io.close(file)
        return levelsArray
    end
    return levels
end

function saveInfo()
    local base = system.pathForFile("levels.json", system.DocumentsDirectory)
    local file = io.open(base, "w")
    local jsoncontents = json.encode(levels)
    file:write(jsoncontents)
    io.close(file)
end
```

And this is my saving and loading file. Can anyone see what's wrong and why only level one is changed?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't changing the table values of the next levels.

This is your code for level one. You simply arent handling anything but level 1.

```
if (levels[1]) then
levels[1] = 3
levels[2] = 1
```

You should, when level 2 is complete. Do the following

```
levels[2] = 3
levels[3] = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, i can't believe i was missing that.